# Finding the index of the second match of a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I am trying to rename files to match the naming convention for plex mediaserver. ( SxxEyy )

Now I have a ton of files that use eg. 411 for S04E11. I have written a little function that will search for an occurrence of this pattern and replace it with the correct convention. Like this :

```
pattern1 = re.compile('[Ss]\\d+[Ee]\\d+')
pattern2 = re.compile('[\.\-]\d{3,4}')

def plexify_name(string):
    #If the file matches the pattern we want, don't change it
    if pattern1.search(string):
        return string
    elif pattern2.search(string):
        piece_to_change = pattern2.search(string)
        endpos = piece_to_change.end()
        startpos = piece_to_change.start()
        #Cut out the piece to change
        cut = string[startpos+1:endpos-1]
        if len(cut) == 4:
            cut = 'S'+cut[0:2] + 'E' + cut[2:4]
        if len(cut) == 3:
            cut = 'S0'+cut[0:1] + 'E' + cut[1:3]
        return string[0:startpos+1] + cut + string[endpos-1:]
```

And this works very well. But it turns out that some of the filenames will have a year in them eg. the.flash.2014.118.mp4 In which case it will change the 2014.

I tried using

```
pattern2.findall(string)
```

Which does return a list of strings like this --> ['.2014', '.118'] but what I want is a list of matchobjects so I can check if there is 2 and in that case use the start/end of the second. I can't seem to find something to do this in the re documentation. I am missing something or do I need to take a totally different approach?

Comment: There is a problem with your code. If I try `the.flash.118.mp4` it can't find `118` there.

Comment: Well I just did this on my console:

`string = "the.flash.2014.118.hdtv-lol.mp4"`
`pattern2 = re.compile('[\.\-]\d{3,4}')`
`string = "the.flash.2014.118.mp4"`
`result = pattern2.search(string)`
`result`
`<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 14), match='.2014'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try anchoring the match to the file extension:

```
pattern2 = re.compile(r'[.-]\d{3,4}(?=[.]mp4$)')
```

Here, `(?= ... )` is a look-ahead assertion, meaning that the thing has to be there for the regex to match, but it's not part of the match:

```
>>> pattern2.findall('test.118.mp4')
['.118']
>>> pattern2.findall('test.2014.118.mp4')
['.118']
>>> pattern2.findall('test.123.mp4.118.mp4')
['.118']
```

Of course, you want it to work with all possible extensions:

```
>>> p2 = re.compile(r'[.-]\d{3,4}(?=[.][^.]+$)')
>>> p2.findall('test.2014.118.avi')
['.118']
>>> p2.findall('test.2014.118.mov')
['.118']
```

If there is more stuff between the episode number and the extension, regexes for matching that start to get tricky, so I would suggest a non-regex approach for dealing with that:

```
>>> f = 'test.123.castle.2014.118.x264.mp4'
>>> [p for p in f.split('.') if p.isdigit()][-1]
'118'
```

Or, alternatively, you can get match objects for all matches by using `finditer` and expanding the iterator by converting it to a list:

```
>>> p2 = re.compile(r'[.-]\d{3,4}')
>>> f = 'test.2014.712.x264.mp4'
>>> matches = list(p2.finditer(f))
>>> matches[-1].group(0)
'.712'
```

Comment: That wouldn't work unfortunately cause it won't always be a .mp4 file and there might be things between 118 and .mp4

This is another example: castle.2009.723.x264.mp4

Also the findall returns strings, I was hoping to find all matchObjects. It seems like `finditer()` does this but I am not sure you can check how many objects are in an iterable before iterating.

Comment: You can expand the iterator by converting it to a list: `matches = list(re.finditer(...))`. In that way you can know how many matches there will be.

Comment: Cool that would probably work :) If you throw that in your original answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Fair enough, I just did :)